# javascript utf-8 encoded text being interpreted as unicode

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, wso2

I'm sending utf-8 encoded text to a wso2 service bus. The service bus interprets this as unicode. In the header the encoding is specified and the character type is also set as utf-8.

When sending the µ, it gets send as C2 B5. If I check this on the utf-8 codepage its the µ sign. But the bus thinks its C2 = Â and B5 = µ.

Does anyone know how to prevent or fix this?

EDIT:

The json my client send to the WSO32

> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
>   Accept-Language: nl-BE
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; MSAppHost/1.0)
>   Host: app1.o.esb.local
>   Content-Length: 156
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Pragma: no-cache

{"meldingen":{"MeldingDto":[{"Id":-1,"Code":"","MeldingTijd":"2014-06-20T15:34:52.680+02:00","Melder":"ABW_PN","Commentaar":"testµ","InterventieId":381}]}}

Here in the hexview in fiddler the µ sign is C2 B5.

The WSO2 service sees this as 2 characters instead of one.

When I use soapUI and send the same character gets send as, B5 and that gets interpreted correctly. I would expect that the WSO2 would know how to handle UTF-8.

Should I edit my encoding to send B5 instead of C2 B5 or does the WSO2 esb need an aditional setting so it knows how to interpret the UTF8 encoding correctly?

Thanks in advance

Ian

Comment: he he he... this means you need to serialize the data before sending to the WS... and you will get it properly

Comment: Wow, the service interprets Unicode data as Unicode data. Will wonders never cease? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: I've tried var dataasString = JSON.stringify(data); but it didn't help.

Comment: as stated above the service interprets utf-8 as unicode.

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding! The service interprets UTF-8 encoded text wrongly as Latin-1 encoded text (or some such variation).

Comment: It's unclear how we can help you here. What encoding does the service expect to receive?!

Comment: I'll edit the question with my test results. Give me some time please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My collegues and I figured out how to fix this. On the client we encoded the message in the following manner:

> encodeURIComponent(comment);

In the case of the µ sign we got %C2%B5.

Then on the server side WSO2 we used a javascript function (local entry):

```
function decode(mc)
{
                var Input = mc.getProperty('InputdecodeURIComponent').toString();
                var Output = decodeURIComponent(Input);
                mc.setProperty('OutputdecodeURIComponent', Output);
}

<property name="InputdecodeURIComponent" value=”ZET HIER ENCODED VALUE” />
<script language="js" key="HelperFunctions.js" function="decodeXml"/>
<property name="Output" expression="get-property('OutputdecodeURIComponent')"/>
```

I hope this helps.

Regards

Ian